# Semisimple Frobenius Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9712025.pdf) and am stuck on the proof of theorem 3.4 on page 7.  In particular, how does the author justify the statement below

> If some component A′ of A is not a field, then it contains nontrivial
>   nilpotents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Context**: $A$ is assumed to be a commutative Frobenius algebra over some field $k$, and $A^{\prime}$ is a factor in the decomposition of $A$ as a product of local $k$-algebras.

The author's claim then follows since (as a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra) $A^{\prime}$ as Artinian local, hence its maximal ideal is nilpotent. Therefore $A^{\prime}$ is a field if and only if its maximal ideal is the zero idealif and only if it has no nontrivial nilpotents.